# AttributeError 'class name' object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, numpy, class, object

```
import numpy as np
import math

class CellLinked ():

    def __init__ (self, box_len: float, r_cut: float) :
        """
        This class initialize with simulation box (L*L*L).
        Here, L=box_len and r_cut is a cut-off radius.
        no_cells is number of cell per axis
        """
        self.box_len = box_len
        self.r_cut = r_cut
        self.no_cells = math.floor (self.box_len/self.r_cut)

    def __call__ (self, postate: np.ndarray) :

        """ 
            Compute the head and list array using simulation box length, cut-off radius, and the position state.

            Parameters:
                postate (np.ndarray):       position of particles

            Returns
                head_arr (list):   head array in the linked list (head_arr.shape==number of cells)
                list_arr (list):   list array in the linked list (list_arr.shape==number of particles)
        """

        # Initialize a Head array with -1, size = the total number of cells
        head_arr = [-1] * self.no_cells*self.no_cells*self.no_cells

        # Initialize a list array with -1, size = the total number of particles
        list_arr = [-1] * postate.shape[0]

        for i in range (0, postate.shape[0]) :

            # calculate cell index of each particles based on the particle position
            index = self._cellindex (postate[i,:])

            # calculate list array
            list_arr [i] = head_arr [index]

            # calculate head array         
            head_arr [index] = i

        return head_arr, list_arr


            


    def _cellindex (self, postate) :

        """ Calculate the cell index based on the i, j, and k index
        """
        i = math.floor (postate[0]/self.r_cut)
        j = math.floor (postate[1]/self.r_cut)
        k = math.floor (postate[2]/self.r_cut)
        return int (k+j*self.no_cells+i*self.no_cells*self.no_cells)

    def _find_neighbor_index (self, cellind) :

        """
        calculate neighbor cell index based on the cell index
        """
        #  calculate i, j, and k index based on the cell index

        i_counter = math.floor (cellind/self.no_cells**2)
        j_counter = math.floor ((cellind - i_counter*self.no_cells**2)/self.no_cells)
        k_counter = math.floor (cellind - j_counter*self.no_cells - i_counter*self.no_cells**2)
      

        # calculate neighbor cell index for each cell index
        index = [-1,0,1]
        neighbor_cell_inx = []
        for ii in index :
            for jj in index :
                for kk in index :
                    if 0 <= ii + i_counter < self.no_cells and 0 <= jj + j_counter < self.no_cells and 0 <= kk + k_counter < self.no_cells :
                        new_index = (kk + k_counter) + (jj + j_counter) *self.no_cells + (ii + i_counter) *self.no_cells*self.no_cells
                        neighbor_cell_inx.append(new_index)
        return neighbor_cell_inx

    def _find_neighbor_cells (self, head_arr) :

        """
        calculate neighbor cells based on head array
        """

        neighbor_cells = []
        for j in range (0, len (head_arr)) :           
            neighbor_cell_inx = self._find_neighbor_index (j)           
            neighbor_cells.append(neighbor_cell_inx)

        return neighbor_cells
    
    def _find_particles_inside_neighbor_cells (self, list_arr, head_arr, neighbor_cells) :
    
        """
        find particles in each cell and neighbor cells are identified
        """
        new_head_arr =[]
        for i in neighbor_cells :
            new_head_arr.append (head_arr[i])
        temporary_state = np.zeros((1,3))

        for ii in new_head_arr:
            if ii > -1 :
                cell_state = np.zeros((1,3))
                cell_state = np.concatenate((cell_state, np.array ([postate[ii]])))
                while  list_arr[ii] != -1 :
                    cell_state = np.concatenate((cell_state, np.array ([postate[list_arr[ii]]])))
                    ii = list_arr[ii]

                cell_state = np.flip(cell_state[1:, :], 0)
                temporary_state = np.concatenate((temporary_state, cell_state))
        
        temporary_state = temporary_state[1:, :]
        return temporary_state




if __name__=="__main__":

    box_len=3
    r_cut= 1
    postate = box_len * np.random.random_sample((50, 3))
    model = CellLinked (box_len,  r_cut)
    head_arr, list_arr = model (postate)
    neighbor_cells = model._find_neighbor_cells(head_arr)
    neighbor_cells = neighbor_cells[13]
    temporary_state = model._find_particles_inside_neighbor_cells (list_arr, head_arr, neighbor_cells)

    mask = np.isin(postate, temporary_state)
    assert np.all(mask == True) == True, 'particles in neighbor cells has been indetified wrongly'

    print ("the head array is : \n ", head_arr)
    print ("list array is : \n ", list_arr)
```

Hi Guys, I have a silly problem when calling the "_find_particles_inside_neighbor_cells" by creating an object from this class. when I run this code here by using "if **name**=="**main**":", code run successfully. but when I want to import this class in another file in a python file like this :

```
import numpy as np
from cell_linked_list import CellLinked

box_len=3
r_cut= 1
postate = box_len * np.random.random_sample((50, 3))
model = CellLinked (box_len,  r_cut)
head_arr, list_arr = model (postate)
neighbor_cells = model._find_neighbor_cells(head_arr)
neighbor_cells = neighbor_cells[13]
temporary_state = model._find_particles_inside_neighbor_cells (list_arr, head_arr, neighbor_cells)

mask = np.isin(postate, temporary_state)
assert np.all(mask == True) == True, 'particles in neighbor cells has been indetified wrongly'
print ('\n')
print ('--------------------------------------------------')
print ('the CellLinked class is verified by the given test')
print ('--------------------------------------------------')
```

While using the above test function, this error appears:

```
temporary_state = model._find_particles_inside_neighbor_cells (list_arr, head_arr, neighbor_cells)
AttributeError: 'CellLinked' object has no attribute '_find_particles_inside_neighbor_cells'
```

I would appreciate it if you take a look at this error and tell me how can I solve this error.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please show the full traceback?

Comment: are you sure you dont have another module with the same name? try importing `cell_linked_list ` and looking at `cell_linked_list.__file__`

Comment: Is the issue resolved? Please mark the answer as accepted to close it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not what you are getting when I tried it on my machine.

It happens due to the fact that  your global variable `postate` is defined inside the conditional `if __name__ == "__main__":` which won't be executed when you import this module in some other module. To overcome this, you have to define the `postate` variable outside your if conditional, at a global level in your module `cell_linked_list`, along with the variables `box_len` and `r_cut`.

```
box_len = 3
r_cut = 1
postate = box_len * np.random.random_sample((50, 3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # rest of your code (which won't be executed if this module is imported in some other file)
```

Also need to make changes in your second module since you need to update the global variables of your imported module `cell_linked_list`:

```
import numpy as np
import cell_linked_list as so
from cell_linked_list import CellLinked

so.box_len = 3
so.r_cut = 1
so.postate = so.box_len * np.random.random_sample((50, 3))
model = CellLinked(so.box_len, so.r_cut)
head_arr, list_arr = model(so.postate)
neighbor_cells = model._find_neighbor_cells(head_arr)
neighbor_cells = neighbor_cells[13]
temporary_state = model._find_particles_inside_neighbor_cells(
list_arr, head_arr, neighbor_cells)

mask = np.isin(so.postate, temporary_state)
assert np.all(
    mask ==
    True) == True, 'particles in neighbor cells has been indetified wrongly'
print('\n')
print('--------------------------------------------------')
print('the CellLinked class is verified by the given test')
print('--------------------------------------------------')
```

One suggestion, you should have the variables `box_len`, `r_cut` and `postate` as your class's variables and initialize them in the class's constructor instead.

Comment: @JavadKasravi If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted (click on the gray tick) to close it.